# Proton-electron inability of annihilation

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

Why would an electron annihilate with a positron if it sees one nearby but would prefer to orbit the proton rather than annihilate with it, despite that the force of attraction being the same?

Comment: The positron is the antiparticle of the electron. The proton is not.

Comment: BTW: The electron and positron will orbit for a short while before annihilating: See the wikipedia entry on positronium. Until the particle/antiparticle pair annihilate, the electron/positron 'atom' behaves a lot like a lighter version of hydrogen.

Answer (score 3):

An electron will only annihilate with its antiparticle, in this case the positron. If the positron was not the antiparticle of the electron then it would fall into its potential well and stay in "orbit" like it does with the proton, but in this case it's energetically favorable to annihilate and release 2 photons.

Answer (score 3):

The reason an electron and positron may interact is simply because of a term,

$$\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}\sim e \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu A_{\mu}\psi$$

in the full Lagrangian of quantum electrodynamics which gives rise to a Feynman vertex with a photon, electron and positron pictorially represented by the diagram,

[image]

A proton is a hadron composed of three quarks, which are fermions and are described by quantum chromodynamics; they interact through the strong force described by an $SU(3)$ gauge theory.

Comment: The electrons do interact electromagnetically with the proton too, but the quantum numbers do not match for annihilation. (There exists also a positronium bound state to compare with the hydrogen bound state, but the S=0 modes give a large probability for annihilation in the e+e- case).